# Error in Liquibase IndexExists precondition : Invalid object name ‘SYS.INDEXES’

Tags: sql-server, liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am facing this issue while running the pre-condition of indexExists in SQL Server. I have noticed a similar bug reported in liquibase https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3107. I don't see it being closed. Is the bug resolved in later versions. Is there any workaround this issue?

- Liquibase version 3.5.3
- SQL Server version 14

Comment: What do you really mean by "SQL Server version 12" - are you talking about SQL Server **2012** (internally v11), or d you really mean SQL Server v12 ( = SQL Server **2014**)  - please clarify

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking the Liquibase developers this question? The last line of the case comment is: "_The problem is, in the SELECT command the Tablename 'SYS.INDEXES' is in uppercases. The Database is case sensitive (Latin1_General_CS_AS) and the real  table name is in lower case_", that's something they need to fix.

Comment: With `version 14` are you referring to SQL Server 2014 or to SQL Server 2017 (**internal** version 14.0)

Comment: SQL Server 2014